# How to write a new line( if it is not in file) and update (if it has in file)

Tags: android, string, bufferedreader

I have a file which is "content.txt". At the first, if the file doesn't exists, I will create it and write the detail in the file as

```
"123,abc"
```

Then If I want to update the "abc" to "abcd". I used below code. Now, my issue is that If I want to add more line which does not equal first field "123", then it will append in the file. However, it does not append in my file. What is happend in my code? Could you help me to fix it

This is example. First my file is empty. I put the String `"123,abc"` then the content in the file is

```
123,abc
```

Then I insert "abcd" to update the its second field. The content of file is

```
123,abcd
```

Now, I insert a new field `456,xyz` which does not equal 123 then the file is

```
123,abcd
456,xyz
```

This is my code

```
String whole_content="123,abc";
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String filename=filepath+  "/" + "content.txt"  ;
boolean flagdataempty=false;
File file = null;
try {
    file =new File(filename);
    // if file doesn't exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {

        file.createNewFile();
        flagdataempty=true;
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String tempFilename=filepath+"/" + "content_temp.txt";
File tempFile = new File(tempFilename);
BufferedReader reader = null;
BufferedWriter writer =null;
boolean flagsearch=false;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    String currentLine;
    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        flagdataempty=false;
        // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        String[] separated = trimmedLine.split(",");
        String classID_out = separated[1].trim(); // this will contain data
        if(classID_out.equals("abc"))
        {
            currentLine=separated[0].trim()+","+"abcd";
            writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            flagsearch=true;
        }
        else
            writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    if(flagdataempty|!flagsearch) {
        writer.write(whole_content + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    writer.close();
    reader.close();
    boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(file);
```

Update: I done by using flag. It will set true if I find 123. Otherwise,I will write the new line. Thanks

Comment: is this working according to your statement **Now, I insert a new field 456,xyz which does not equal 123 then the file is**

Comment: 123,abcd
456,xyz   That means if the 456,xyz did not containt in the file. It will append in the file

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the code actually trying to write the content you want to write, but give following code a try, as you want to add next text which does not contain 123 to the next line.

```
 if(classID_out.equals("abc"))
    {
        currentLine=separated[0].trim()+","+"abcd";
        writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }else{
       Files.write(Paths.get("filepath+  "/" + "content.txt"), "\n456,xyz".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }
```

I would not recommend this kind of fashion to read and write data which would change over the time and you constantly will have a lot of hustle reading and writing the data to it,

the Best way would be is to write **JSON** or **XML** of a serialized way to the text file. it will remove the headache of dealing with low level functions as you would have your object populated thought **[GSON](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)** or **[Simple XML Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)**.

In a case I would suggest have a **ArrayList** of object which will be written to the text file, read the text file and populate your **ArrayList** from that, and then try adding something to the arraylist, if it already exist it wont add to the arrylist and if does not exist it will add to the arrylist, after your work is done with the Arraylist, write that to the text file again

Comment: I am working in temp file. And then I will rename it to original file. So, I think if we write it directly in the original file, then it is not true. My problem is that I want to write a new line to file if the line does not exist in file (detected by first field of the line, for example 456,xyz then 456 is not same with other id then it is new line.) Otherwise, if I insert a new line as (123,abcd) then 123 already has in the file, I only want to update the second field 'abc' to 'abcd'

Comment: Thank Pankaj Nimgade. I think I done it. I used flag. I will update my question

Comment: @user3051460, great mate you found the solution